# DataTables Table not populating

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I have an application where I execute queries stored in a database.  Each one is potentially against different tables with a different set of columns retrieved.  Similar to an application that executes ad-hoc queries.

So I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function populateSummaryReport() {

if ($('#summaryTable').length) {
    $('#sumaryTable').remove;
}


const getReport = {
    jobID: $('#jobID').val(),
    beginDate: $('#summaryStart').val(),
    endDate: $('#summaryEnd').val(),
    tableType: 'Summary'};

$.ajax({
    url: "php/reports.php",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(getReport)
}).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //success

    if (response["tableColumns"][0].substring(0, 4) === "<h4>") { //if html returned here no detail query
        $('summaryReportPlaceholder').html(response);
    } else {

//build table
        var tableDef =
                "<table id='summaryTable' class='display' width='100%'>" +
                "<caption>" + $('#jobID').val() + " Summary Report</caption>" +
                "<thead><tr>";
        //build thead 
        for (const colName of response["tableColumns"]) {
            tableDef += "<th>" + colName + "</th>";
            
        }
        
        tableDef += "</tr></thead></table>";
        
        $('#summaryReportPlaceholder').html(tableDef);
        $('#summaryTable').DataTable({

            select: {
                sytle: 'single',
                items: 'row'
            },
            data: response["tableData"],
            //
            //columns: response["tableColumns"],
            dataSrc: "",
            paging: false,
            scrollY: '60vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            order: []
        });
    }
}).fail(function (jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error " + textStatus + "  " + jqHXR + " " + errorThrown);
}).always(function (jqxHRorData, textStatus, jqXHROrErrorThrown) {
    alert("complete");
});

}
```

This code gets executed (call from another function);  reports.php returns the expected json and the code falls into the .done function.  I am expecting #summaryTable to be populated, but it is not.  I do get a table with the appropriate number of rows, but the data is all blanks.

I took as my inspiration the following post: [bindrid / datatables forums](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/112268/#Comment_112268)

Note:  Since my original post I moved the build of the table to the .done section of the ajax call, and added column names.  I now get the following warning (twice)  DataTables warning: table id=summaryTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I did lookup the above url but, I don't see where my data fits any of the scenarios described.  Some of it is Greek to me so I could be missing something.

Comment: What have yout ried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If the PHP backend returns the proper data, in the expected format, is this question even related to PHP itself? If yes, please share the code. If not, please remove the tag

Comment: Hi Nico,  Please see my answer below.  I did not originally tag php, but it turned out my issue was actually with my php code, as it returned an associative array where I needed a regular array.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

When DataTables applied the

```
data: response["tableData"]
```

it treated response["tableData"] as a numerically indexed array because the column mapping was not definede in a columns option.

What reports.php returned was an associative array:

```
oci_fetch_array($tableQuery, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
```

Chaning this code in reports.php to:

```
oci_fetch_array($tableQuery, OCI_NUM + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
```

solved my issue.